Generate WADL is blank in SoapUI
I have WCF webservice project in C#. I created the REST project in SoapUI. I tested it and get the result.   When I generate the WADL file, it is succeed but the file is blank. Would someone tell me what is missed.
There is the method:
[OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
     UriTemplate = "GetList?Id={Id}&DATE={DATE}&item={item}")]             
 List<Info> GetList(string Id, string DATE, string item);



 [DataContract]
 public class Info
 {
     
     [DataMember] public string LastName { get; set; }
     [DataMember] public string GivenName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
     [DataMember] public string InitiaName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

The endpoint in the SoupUI for testing
https://localhost:8011/ORDERS.svc/GetList?DATE=2022-2-16&Id=8816123.0001&item=btn

Would someone tell me how to do it. thanks.
